# Datareader is incompatible with the specified 'result set complex type'. A member of the type

Tags: entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that updates a date column in a table in MS SQL Server database. This stored procedure does not have any complex logic. It does a simple update on the date column with the value passed in its input parameter. This stored procedure does not return any result set upon successful execution but returns a result set with a few columns with names ErrorNumber, ErrorSeverity etc., when the stored procedure execution throws an exception from the try..catch exception handling block.

I am using DB First entity approach; I have updated Entity Data Model for this stored procedure from my asp.net MVC web application. Entity framework designer generated a complex type for the return type on this stored procedure with a property for each of the columns in the columns list returned in the catch block. When I invoked the stored procedure from asp.net MVC application with valid input parameters, I encountered the "Datareader is incompatible exception". I know this exception is triggered by entity framework because the stored procedure execution does not return a result set and the framework is expecting a column to be returned back with the name "ErrorNumber". I invoked the stored procedure directly with the db context instance with required valid parameter values.
for example db.UpdateProcedure(dueDate). I did not use a data table to load the data from the data reader. I know loading the result set into a data table will not cause this exception.

After making a minor change to the stored procedure to return @@rowcount on successful execution, the application did not throw this exception upon this stored procedure invocation.

I am wondering if there is a better way to deal with this situation without updating the stored procedure to return @@rowcount.

I am using the designer generated entity model from the database; I did not make any manual changes to the schema after auto-generation of the entity model. To be honest, I don't like doing manual changes to the schema once it is auto-generated.

Is there anything I am missing during the entity schema update for this stored procedure to have correct complex type generated when the model is updated from entity designer?

Is the stored procedure returning a result set upon exception occurrence and not returning any result upon successful execution causing any problem to the process that updates entity schema?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: EF is never going to like a stored procedure that returns a result set _sometimes_.  And returning error information in a result set is a bad practice.  If you just let the errors go to the client or `throw` one of your own, it's better.

Comment: Hello David, Please let me know why returning error information in a result set is a bad practice. Also, can you please point me to an web link/resource where I can gain much insight into best practices for error handling with asp.net  MVC front end and MS SQL server as backend?

Comment: Short answer is that common practice in .NET is to use exceptions, so you should do that when designing anything intended to be called from .NET.  See eg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exception-throwing